# convert thumbnail image quality issue

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using below ImageMagick convert thumbnail command to generate thumbnail from a high quality image, but the generated images is not clear as the original one and it is blurry and test are difficult to read.

Below is the command :-

convert  -thumbnail 612x264 inputImage.gif outPutImage.gif;

Is there any quality for converet thumbnail which I am missing.

I am also attaching the input and output images link

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Uck.jpg): [image]

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MFuA.gif): [image]

Someone please help, thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: Your "input image" link seems to be to a JPEG not a GIF.

Comment: That's probably because the SE uploader converted them...

Comment: @Glenn Images are gif you can save by Save as Image.

Comment: Hi Circle B, can you please give some detail. Is there something with my environment or version.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the quality parameter http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/?

Comment: Please add the explanation provided in the linked resource into the post (the resource may be deleted in the future). See [answer].